# AndEngine add single image multiple time in different size

Tags: android, textures, sprite, andengine, scene

I am new in AndEngine. I am using following code to display an image of a ball.

```
private ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion;
private Sprite ball1;

@Override
public void onCreateResources() {
   ITexture ball = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
             new IInputStreamOpener() {
                    @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ball.png");
                        }
            });
  this.mBallTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);

  ....................
  ....................
}


@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
   final Scene scene = new Scene();
   scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
   ...........
   ball1 = new Sprite(192, 63, this.mBallTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
   scene.attachChild(ball1);
   ..............
   ...........  

}
```

Now, depending on the game level I want to add multiple ball of different size in the scene. Is it possible to add `ITextureRegion mBallTextureRegion` multiple time in different size(using different magnifying it)? If it is, then how? Please help me this sample code.

Comment: There is other Sprite constructors, use Sprite(x, y, w, h, textureRegion, vetexBufferObjectManager). Assign different w and h, so, you can have different size sprites. Or, you can use Sprite methods setScale/setScaleX/setScaleY to change the sprite size after you have created the sprite.

Comment: Did you checked the `AndEngien` samples there are many thing covered in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to resize a Sprite,AnimatedSprite,Text,etc...

```
//the original image x2, 2f because the parameter is float
youSprite.setScale(2f);
```

if you use a texture region in more sprites:

```
Sprite youSprite; 
 //set deepCopy() in you texture to optimized memory
youSprite= new Sprite(0,0,youTexture.deepCopy(),mEnginge.getVertexTextureManager());
```

and if you want generate random position of each ball use "Random" variable.

best regards.